# Mimicking classical inheritance with Object.create()

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance

I'm going through a topic on MDN. I get about halfway through and I can't fully grasp what is happening.  I'd like to be able to read this code but I'm stuck.  Any help or input would be greatly appreciated.

[Classical inheritance with Object.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

- The first function `Shape()` is easy enough.  It's a Constructor.
- The next section is also straightforward.  `Shape.prototype.move` is a method added to the Shape prototype.
- The next Constructor `Rectangle()` is where I start to lose it.  I translate `Shape.call(this)` to mean `Shape` calls an object which is `this`.  But what does `this` point at and why is this line needed?
- In the next to last section I might be thoroughly lost.  `Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype)`  Does this mean make the Rectangle prototype the Shape prototype?
- The last item I can't translate.  `Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle`.  What is actually happening?

```js
// Shape - superclass
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}

// superclass method
Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
  console.info('Shape moved.');
};

// Rectangle - subclass
function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this); // call super constructor.
}

// subclass extends superclass
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

var rect = new Rectangle();

console.log('Is rect an instance of Rectangle?',
  rect instanceof Rectangle); // true
console.log('Is rect an instance of Shape?',
  rect instanceof Shape); // true
rect.move(1, 1); // Outputs, 'Shape moved.'
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: @melpomene  I have no problem with a generic call.  But in this case I'm lost.  Functions call objects.  But this looks nonstandard to me.  I can't follow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is the newly created Rectangle instance inside of the Rectangle constructor.

```
  Shape.call(this);
```

Will call the Shape constructor with `this` being the new Rectangle. This line is needed so that this ...

```
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
```

... gets executed on the Rectangle.

---

```
  Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype)
```

Here it is defined that the Rectangles prototype, which all Rectangles extend from, inherits from the Shapes prototype. Therefore, all Rectangles also get the Shapes methods.

---

```
  Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle
```

That just ensures that `.constructor()` works as exected on Rectangles:

```
  const rect = new Rectangle();
  const rect2 = new rect.constructor();
```

Comment: 100% fascinating!  Does this line mean it picks up Shapes methods and loses its own methods or is this a += situation?  `Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype)`

Comment: @DR01D properties are looked up in the object itself (e.g. `rect`), then in its prototype (`Rectangle.prototype`), then in the prototypes prototype (`Shape.prototype`) and then in the prototypes prototypes prototype (`Object.prototype`) so yes, it wont loose its methods